# How embeddings_initializer of Embeddings instance in keras is set

Tags: keras

When we create Embeddings instance in keras, we set the `embeddings_initializer` variable as `initializers.get(embeddings_initializer)` to set to set the initial random weights of Keras layers.

When I go to line https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/45c838cc7a0a5830c0a54a2f58f48fc61950eb68/keras/initializers.py#L488 , to see the definition of get(), there are 3 if else cases, which of those if else cases are executed?

The context of asking this question was when are the inital random weights assigned to the Embedding instance. So are they being assigned when we are creating the object or some time later?
My personal intuition is that third condition is executed but I do not know how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These `get` functions are auxiliary functions to transform strings into actual initializer objects.

- In case 1, you pass a `dict`, then it transforms the dict into an initializer.
- In case 2, you pass a `string`, then it transforms the string into an initializer.
- In case 3, you pass an actual initializer (a callable object).

There is nothing special in this part of the code. The actual initializers are all the classes and functions defined above, such as `RandomUniform`, `Orthogonal`, `lecun_uniform`, `glorot_normal`, etc.

Comment: The context of asking this question was when are the inital random weights assigned to the Embedding instance. So are they being assigned when we are creating the object or some time later?